# asp.net how to retrieve data from database in my controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a model like this

```
class Student 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string College {get;set;}
}
```

I have a Homecontroller method like this,

```
public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            Student data = new Student();
            return Json(data.Name);
        }
```

The json data it is returning is null. However I have few rows of data in my database. How do I return all the "Name" in my database when above method is called for my ajax?

Comment: You are not quite at the point where you should be asking a question. The first thing you should do (before asking a question), is research the problem, and try something. Then if you don't succeed, you paste the code you have, your research and understand, what you expect and whats happening.

Comment: You should use your `DbContext` to connect to your database.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi I was actually lost not knowing what to search.Thank you for pointing me right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("StudentMaster")]  //write here table name
public class Student
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string College {get;set;}
}
```

and then create a context class for your database referance

Controller

```
//here you need to create a context class object

dbcontext _contextclass = new dbcontext(); 

public ActionResult GetData()
{      
    return View(db._contextclass .ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance @Rahul. I received an "no database provider" error for above codes. But later found that I need to slightly modify above code by using "using ()" pattern or dependency injection pattern for it work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pal If you work with entity framework then no need to create context class remember that or if you work with code first approach then create a context class. the context class is nothing but mediator between our application and SQL